# Pandas- Dividing a column by another column conditional on if values are greater than 0?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains dates, items, and 2 values. All I'm looking to do is output another column that is the product of column A / column B if column B is greater than 0, and 0 if column B is equal to 0.

```
   date     item   A   B        C       
 1/1/2017   a      0   3             0  
 1/1/2017   b      2   0             0  
 1/1/2017   c      5   2           2.5  
 1/1/2017   d      4   1             4  
 1/1/2017   e      3   3             1  
 1/1/2017   f      0   4             0  
 1/2/2017   a      3   3             1  
 1/2/2017   b      2   2             1  
 1/2/2017   c      3   9   0.333333333  
 1/2/2017   d      4   0             0  
 1/2/2017   e      5   3   1.666666667  
 1/2/2017   f      3   0             0
```

this is the code I've written, but the kernel keeps dying (keep in mind this is just an example table, I have about 30,000 rows so nothing too crazy)

```
df['C'] = df.loc[df['B'] > 0, 'A'] / df['B'])
```

any idea on what's going on? Is something running infinitely that's causing it to crash? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it crash on a smaller dataframe? A-priori it sounds like a bug. Try to narrow down to the row / set of rows which causes the crash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get that using `np.where`

```
df['C'] = np.round(np.where(df['B'] > 0, df['A']/df['B'], 0), 1)
```

Or if you want to use `loc`

```
df.loc[df['B'] > 0, 'C'] = df['A']/df['B']
```

and then `fillna(0)`

Comment: Nice one. This would've been my first option.

Comment: that's great- thanks for sharing! Maybe it's an error on my end, but I'm getting an issue that a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe? I didn't have that issue prior so I'm wondering if this script is causing that.

Comment: @DickThompson, did you create this dataframe by taking a slice of a larger dataframe?

Comment: Check this link, it explains the issue really well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help- I guess I am just confused. So what I'm also trying to do is to basically get a comparison of each item vs the entire group, so the values in one of the column is just a groupby of values of each item for a date subtracted by the value for that row. ie `df['A'] = df['B'].groupby['date'].transform('sum') - df['B']`   so what would the correct way to do this? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Can you post the earlier code in the post? I am not able to understand the issue from the groupby

Comment: Ok, so when you say df['B'], you are just looking at the series (one single column) and hence saying df['B'].groupby('date') doesnt work as there is no date column in df['B']. You need df.groupby('date').B.transform('sum')

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work? still getting the same copy a slice error

Comment: I'm also confused because when I run the groupby I don't get that error, only when I'm running the division

Comment: Can you post a full traceback? It would be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Post the original df, then grouping and division

Comment: sorry for the confusion- maybe it could also have something to do with another transformation I did? I tried to make 2 copies of a column by literally just doing `df['A rolling'] = df['A rolling'].rolling(10).mean()`  I'm confused though because whenever I run any of these functions I don't get this error, only when I try dividing the columns...

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
You use `pd.Series.mask` to hide zeros, and then just empty cells with `fillna`.

```
v = (df.A / df.B.mask(df.B == 0)).fillna(0)
v

0     0.000000
1     0.000000
2     2.500000
3     4.000000
4     1.000000
5     0.000000
6     1.000000
7     1.000000
8     0.333333
9     0.000000
10    1.666667
11    0.000000
dtype: float64

df['C'] = v
```

Alternatively, replace those zeros with `np.inf`, because `x / inf = 0`.

```
df['C'] = (df.A / df.B.mask(df.B == 0, np.inf))
```

---

**Option 2**
Direct replacement with `df.replace`

```
df.A / df.B.replace(0, np.inf)

0     0.000000
1     0.000000
2     2.500000
3     4.000000
4     1.000000
5     0.000000
6     1.000000
7     1.000000
8     0.333333
9     0.000000
10    1.666667
11    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Keep in mind, you can do an `astype` conversion, if you want mixed integers and floats as your result:

```
df.A.div(df.B.replace(0, np.inf)).astype(object)

0            0
1            0
2          2.5
3            4
4            1
5            0
6            1
7            1
8     0.333333
9            0
10     1.66667
11           0
dtype: object
```

Comment: I am about ...post the option 2 :-) haha

Comment: @Wen haha, I can remove it if you wish, you can post it.

Comment: No need , I mean post in your comment .:-) not a answer